# What is causing my Apple ID issues when using that ID on two macOS installations, on the same machine?

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id

I have a single 2019 16" Macbook Pro, and due to a desire to separate my work from personal projects, I have created a new APFS volume to contain my personal work. I installed macOS Big Sur on it and generally things work as expected. Both installations are the latest version of macOS Big Sur (currently 11.4).

Signing into my Apple ID does not work as expected.

I expect to be able to sign in to my single Apple ID on both volumes and be able to use standard Apple ID and iCloud features on both volumes, independently, more or less as if they were two separate devices (in reality it seems that Apple does understand that it is one device, I only have a single "devices list" entry).

However, I am experiencing a problem where signing into the Apple ID on one volume causes the other volume, at the time it is next booted, to have a "problem" with my Apple ID. I encounter a warning message that says there was something "wrong with my Apple ID" and that I needed to "sign-in again" to fix the problem. Visiting System Preferences like the prompt asks shows the following problems:

[image: system preferences apple id warnings]

Pressing "continue" and signing in again solves the problem for the installation/volume that I am currently logged into, but the act of solving this problem here will trigger the same problem in the other volume.

I have googled this problem extensively but cannot find references to my exact situation - multiple volumes/installations with the same Apple ID, with this "Apple ID problem" problem. Generally, people with this "problem with your Apple ID" message do not explicitly say that they are running multiple volumes, and that the problem can be solved either by following the prompts, deleting a corrupted keychain directory (tried that with no luck), or with a sign out -> restart -> sign out (tried that with no luck).

Apple themselves seem to [support this exact multiple-volume setup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891), so either my google-fu is lacking, or nobody has reported this problem before.

Some ancillary questions:

- What impact, if any, does the "computer name" have on this? I can set each volume's computer name to something different. If I do, devices and services seem to use the correct name based on what volume I am logged in to.
- Would installing each OS in separate APFS containers (not volumes) be of any help? I'd like to avoid that in order to keep the benefit of shared free space between volumes.

Any suggestions on how I might proceed?

Comment: 1. You should be using separate containers.  It is much more robust. 2. You should use different computer names. I suspect Apple is confused by you logging in with the same computer name, but a different UUID (each install will have a different value).

Comment: @gilby Do you mind elaborating on why containers are more robust? When I did this a few months back I started with separate computer names, I only recently tried naming them the same thing to see if that fixed it.

Comment: More robust: a) less chance of a mistake due to confusing naming - multiple Data volumes, b) when updating the recovery volume may get a mismatch.

Comment: Also, if you just want to separate work stuff from home stuff, then do you need two separate OSes? Why not just two different user accounts?

Comment: @benwiggy because of invasive software requirements by my employer.

Comment: Also, Apple doesn't support using the same Apple ID on separate user accounts, apparently.